# Route Provider confusion

Tags: javascript, angularjs

New at Angular JS, but this shouldn't really be causing me any issues, yet it is.

Ok, so my setup is like this:

app/storelocator.html
app/stores.html

So from storelocator.html I want to navigate to individual store pages, using this format:

```
<div ng-controller="StoreController as store" class="row" ngcloak>
        <form method='get' id='searchForm' ng-controller="StoreController as storeCtrl" ng-submit="store.submit()">
            <label for="postcode" class="controls__label">Postcode</label>
            <input type="text" name="postcode" placeholder="Search..." ng-model="store.postcode">
            <input type="submit" value="Search">
        </form>

        <br />

        <section class="cards">
            <header ng-show="store.postcode">
                <h2>You searched for {{store.postcode}}</h2>
            </header>
            <article ng-repeat="store in store.stores" class="card">
                <address>
                    <h3 ng-if="store.outlet" class="title">{{store.outlet}}</h3>
                    <p ng-if="store.phone" class="tel">t. {{store.phone}}</p>
                    <p class="address1"><span ng-if="store.addressOne">{{store.addressOne}}, <br /></span>
                        <span ng-if="store.addressTwo">{{store.addressTwo}}, <br /> </span>
                        <span ng-if="store.addressThree">{{store.addressThree}}, <br /></span>
                        <span ng-if="store.town">{{store.town}}, <br /></span>
                        <span ng-if="store.county">{{store.county}}, <br /></span>
                        <span ng-if="store.postCode">{{store.postCode}}</span>
                        <span ng-if="store.distance">{{store.distance}}</span>
                    </p>
                    <a class="btn btn--primary" href="/app/stores/{{store.outlet}}">View Store</a>

                </address>
            </article>
        </section>
    </div>
```

and my controller:

```
'use strict';


angular.module('store',["ngRoute"])
    .config(["$routeProvider", function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/',
        {
            templateURL: "index.html",
            controller: "StoreController",
            controllerAs: "app"
        })
        .when('/stores', {
            template: "store page"
        })
        .otherwise({
            template: "This doesn't exist"
        })
}])

.controller('StoreController', ['$http',function($http){
    var store = this;
    store.stores = [];
    $http.get('my/json/file').success(function(data){
        store.stores = data;
    });
    store.submit = function() {

       $http.get('my/json/file' + store.postcode).success(function(data){
            store.stores = data;
        });


    };
}]);
```

What am I doing wrong? Just can't seem to work this one out.

Comment: Do you get any errors in developer console when page is loading?

Answer (score 0):

Way too many mistakes in your code. I will pinpoint two main things: you don't even have a **route for store detail** defined and you didn't turn on **HTML5 routing mode**, so your links won't work without '#'. You better kick start with some working example like: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example

Also next time, please, tell us **exactly what is wrong** and **what are you trying to accomplish**. Error logs and online working code samples (e.g. like Plunker or JSBin) are also helpful.

Comment: Sorry I didn't post any error logs because there wasn't any.  I usually try and do a codepen, but first day back in the office and I'm still a little foggy. :)

I don't know what route for store detail means there, and all the resources I have looked at, none have mentioned HTML5 routing mode, maybe they were assuming too much.  Sorry, I understand this may be frustrating for people.

Comment: Another confusing thing in your code: you state that you have storelocator.html and stores.html template, but you are referencing index.html in your router config. As I said, you better start with working example. Not mentioning other strange things, like subreferencing your StoreController on that form, etc.

Comment: Noted, sorry for wasting everyone's time.